# Load Rich Word document into RichText Editor of telerik editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have some form where I am uploading some word document and saving it on a DB.
Later I have to do some tokenization of these docuement.I currently didn't find anything for loading editor from some file without copy pasting into the editor the content manually.
How can I load Word file [doc or docx] into rich text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this live demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/rtfexport/defaultcs.aspx
and this blog post: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-07-19/how-to-enhance-the-rtf-export-of-radeditor-for-asp.net-ajax